# Node.js Javascript array random function always giving 1st when command is triggered

Tags: javascript, node.js

When command is triggered it always giving 1 in array instead doing it random. What is wrong ?

```
var anArray = ['1','2','3'];
var rand = anArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * anArray.length)];
if (command == "!random") {
    client.chatMessage(`${rand}`);
  }
```

I expected the random resultat but acualy is always giving option 1.

Comment: Seems to work correctly for me: https://jsfiddle.net/jLhvbsdx/

Answer (score 0):

Random algorithm works fine:

```js
 

var anArray = ['1','2','3'];
var rand = anArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * anArray.length)];
console.log(rand);
```

Comment: Yeah it works fine, but you dont see my code or what ? Im trying to show result by command answer and still giving same answer in chat not in log how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Doing the following on a command line (windows):

```
> var anArray = ['1','2','3'];
> console.log(anArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * anArray.length)]);
> console.log(anArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * anArray.length)]);
> console.log(anArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * anArray.length)]);
```

I do get either '1', '2', or '3'.

I ran this using node v8.10.0